# calculator in c# does not start from beginning

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I am stuck on one problem. I  have tried to programe a calculator and calculator on 2nd power. I want me or someone to choose if he wants 
 a "kalkulacka" or "mocninator". When I am done with "mocninator" or "kalkulacka" I want the programe to ask me if I want to run it all again. But there is the problem. Everytime I choose options 1 (mocninator) and then the program asks me if I want to repeat it. I type "ano" (yes) and it starts from kalkulacka. It doesnt ask me If I want to choose the mocninator or kalkulacka. The code might be really bad but as I said, I have been programming for max. 4 hours.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhatAnApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)


    {



        bool kalkulacka = true;
        bool mocninator = false;
        bool pokracovat = true;
        while (pokracovat == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vítejte v mé aplikaci, pro začátek si vyber, jestli chceš spustit kalkulačku nebo mocninátor.");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - mocninátor");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - kalkulačka");
            int volba1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (volba1)
            {
                case 1:
                    mocninator = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    kalkulacka = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste špatnout hodnotu!");
                    break;
            }

            if (mocninator)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vybrál sis mocninátor");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo, které chcete umocnit");
                float s = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double d = s;
                double m = 2;
                Console.WriteLine("Výsledek je: " + Math.Pow(s, m));
                Console.WriteLine("Přeješ si aplikaci spustit znovu? ano/ne");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            else
                pokracovat = true;


            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "ano":
                    pokracovat = true;
                        break;
                case "ne":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
            }

            while (kalkulacka == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pro začátek musíš zadat dvě čísla, se kterými budeš pracovat");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej první číslo: ");
                float a;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej druhé číslo: ");
                float b;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Výborně, teď si vyber operaci: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - sčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - odčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - násobení");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - dělení");
                char volba = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Zvolil jste volbu číslo: " + volba);
                float vysledek = 0;
                bool platnaVolba = true;
                switch (volba)
                {
                    case '1':
                        vysledek = a + b;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        vysledek = a - b;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        vysledek = a * b;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        vysledek = a / b;
                        break;
                    default:
                        platnaVolba = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (platnaVolba)
                    Console.WriteLine("Výsledek: {0}", vysledek);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba operace");
                Console.WriteLine("Přejete si kalkulačku použít znovu? ano/ne");

                platnaVolba = false;
                while (!platnaVolba)
                {
                    switch (Console.ReadLine().ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "ano":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = true;
                            break;
                        case "ne":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba. Zadejte ano/ne !");
                            break;
                    }


                }

                if (pokracovat)
                    Console.Clear();
            }
        }   
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I changed a few things but now it wont start kalkulacka. I do not know why.
  bool kalkulacka = false, when I type 2 at volba1 it should changed to true ---> while(kalkulacka == true) so where is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhatAnApp
{
    class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)


    {

        bool kalkulacka = false;
        bool mocninator = false;
        bool pokracovat = true;
        while (pokracovat == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vítejte v mé aplikaci, pro začátek si vyber, jestli chceš spustit kalkulačku nebo mocninátor.");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - mocninátor");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - kalkulačka");
            int volba1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (volba1)
            {
                case 1:
                    mocninator = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    kalkulacka = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste špatnout hodnotu!");
                    break;
            }

            if (mocninator)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vybrál sis mocninátor");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo, které chcete umocnit");
                float s = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double d = s;
                double m = 2;
                Console.WriteLine("Výsledek je: " + Math.Pow(s, m));
            }
            else
                kalkulacka = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Přeješ si aplikaci spustit znovu? ano/ne");

            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "ano":
                    pokracovat = true;
                    break;
                case "ne":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Špatná hodnota");
                    break;
            }



            while (kalkulacka)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pro začátek musíš zadat dvě čísla, se kterými budeš pracovat");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej první číslo: ");
                float a;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej druhé číslo: ");
                float b;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Výborně, teď si vyber operaci: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - sčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - odčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - násobení");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - dělení");
                char volba = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Zvolil jste volbu číslo: " + volba);
                float vysledek = 0;
                bool platnaVolba = true;
                switch (volba)
                {
                    case '1':
                        vysledek = a + b;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        vysledek = a - b;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        vysledek = a * b;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        vysledek = a / b;
                        break;
                    default:
                        platnaVolba = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (platnaVolba)
                    Console.WriteLine("Výsledek: {0}", vysledek);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba operace");
                Console.WriteLine("Přejete si kalkulačku použít znovu? ano/ne");

                platnaVolba = false;
                while (!platnaVolba)
                {
                    switch (Console.ReadLine().ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "ano":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = true;
                            break;
                        case "ne":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba. Zadejte ano/ne !");
                            break;
                    }


                }

                if (pokracovat)
                    Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }   

    }
}
```

Comment: As part of learning programming, you will need to get used to debugging (stepping through) the code. I'm not sure which IDE you're using, so I can't give specifics, but you'll want to add a/some breakpoint(s) to the area(s) where the program is not behaving as you are expecting, then "Start Debugging".  Or, some IDEs offer you the option to start debugging from the main entry point of the program, allowing you to step through the entire flow of code.   By the way, what language is that?

Comment: Instead of trying to start from scratch and making many mistakes along the way to learn, get a demo project for calculators , run them and see how they work. It will teach you good coding practices, and save you time by starting you up from a much better level. What you want is to learn how to write a better calculator program, so get few of the many sample calculator projects on the net and start from them, Any improvement on this code is waste, you be writing much better after you see some good samples.

Comment: Your code would be a lot more readable and a lot easier to debug if you split it into multiple methods. As it is its really hard to see what the program flow is when you have multiple nested loops that are dozens of lines long. I can however see that at least one potential problem is that because you default `kalulatacka` to true then if you choose case 1 then its sets `mocninator` to true as well so both of them are true. This doesn't seem right if they are making an either or choice and I can see it then incorrectly going into the wrong code as a result of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WhatAnApp
```

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

```
    {

        bool kalkulacka = false;
        bool mocninator = false;
        bool pokracovat = true;
        while (pokracovat == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vítejte v mé aplikaci, pro začátek si vyber, jestli chceš spustit kalkulačku nebo mocninátor.");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - mocninátor");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - kalkulačka");
            int volba1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (volba1)
            {
                case 1:
                    mocninator = true;
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    kalkulacka = true;
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste špatnout hodnotu!");
                    break;
            }

            if (mocninator)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vybrál sis mocninátor");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo, které chcete umocnit");
                float s = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double d = s;
                double m = 2;
                Console.WriteLine("Výsledek je: " + Math.Pow(s, m));
                Console.WriteLine("Přeješ si aplikaci použit znovu? ano/ne");

                switch (Console.ReadLine().ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "ano":
                        pokracovat = true;
                        mocninator = false;
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case "ne":
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Špatná volba");
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (kalkulacka == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pro začátek musíš zadat dvě čísla, se kterými budeš pracovat");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej první číslo: ");
                float a;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Zadej druhé číslo: ");
                float b;
                while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b))
                    Console.WriteLine("Zadal jste neplatné číslo");
                Console.WriteLine("Výborně, teď si vyber operaci: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - sčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - odčítání");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - násobení");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - dělení");
                char volba = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Zvolil jste volbu číslo: " + volba);
                float vysledek = 0;
                bool platnaVolba = true;
                switch (volba)
                {
                    case '1':
                        vysledek = a + b;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        vysledek = a - b;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        vysledek = a * b;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        vysledek = a / b;
                        break;
                    default:
                        platnaVolba = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (platnaVolba)
                    Console.WriteLine("Výsledek: {0}", vysledek);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba operace");
                Console.WriteLine("Přejete si aplikaci použít znovu? ano/ne");

                platnaVolba = false;
                while (!platnaVolba)
                {
                    switch (Console.ReadLine().ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "ano":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = true;
                            kalkulacka = false;
                            Console.Clear();
                            break;
                        case "ne":
                            platnaVolba = true;
                            pokracovat = false;
                            kalkulacka = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Neplatná volba. Zadejte ano/ne !");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}